# Simple synchronization with C signals

Tags: c, posix, signals

I'm trying to solve an exercise which requires that : "the starting process must fork two times. The father and the children must synchronize to write, one after another, in the first position of a temporary file reading the characters written on three different files (one for each process). The program must use signals to implement the synchronization mechanism."

So far i've tried to solve this by doing so :

- P1 (the father) starts reading/writing first. Before stopping himself (through a call to the raise function), he sends a SIGCONT signal to wake up F2 (the second child)
- F2 reads from his file and writes on the temp file. He then stops himself too, and sends a SIGCONT signal to wake up F1 (the first child)
- F1 does the same as F2, but wakes up P1 and so on...

However, i can't get the code working (in some cases, after changing the order of the readings and writings, i got most of the latter in output but the program behavior was always erratic and never terminated).

Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define TEMP_PATH "/tmp/mytempfile"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *writeFp;
FILE *rfpF1;
FILE *rfpF2;
FILE *rfpP1;
pid_t pid1, pid2;

char car;   
char sizeOfChar = sizeof(char);

if (argc != 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s filePath1 filePath2 filePath3\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (access(argv[1], F_OK)==-1){
    perror("access 1 error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (access(argv[2], F_OK)==-1){
    perror("access 2 error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (access(argv[3], F_OK)==-1){
    perror("access 3 error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if((writeFp = fopen(TEMP_PATH, "w")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open temp file on writing.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((rfpP1 = fopen(argv[3], "r")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s on reading.\n", argv[3]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   

switch(pid1 = fork()){
    case -1:
            perror("fork error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    case 0:
            /* F1 : first child */

            if ((rfpF1 = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s on reading.\n", argv[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            raise(SIGSTOP);
            while(fscanf(rfpF1, "%c", &car) != EOF){

                if(fseek(writeFp, 0L, SEEK_SET) == -1){
                    perror("fseek error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if(fprintf(writeFp, "%c", car) != 1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "fprintf error. Terminating...\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }                   

                if(kill(getppid(), SIGCONT) == -1){
                    perror("F1 kill error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                printf("F1 : i've written '%c'\n", car); fflush(stdout);

                // If with the next read EOF is reached, the process doesn't have to stop...
                if(fscanf(rfpF1, "%c", &car) == EOF)
                    break;
                else{
                    if(fseek(rfpF1, -sizeOfChar, SEEK_CUR)){
                        perror("fseek error");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    raise(SIGSTOP);
                }
            }

            fclose(rfpF1);              
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


    default :
            break;  

}


switch(pid2 = fork()){
    case -1:
            perror("fork 2 error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    case 0:
            /* F2 : second child */

            if ((rfpF2 = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s on reading.\n", argv[2]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            raise(SIGSTOP);
            while(fscanf(rfpF2, "%c", &car) != EOF){

                if(fseek(writeFp, 0L, SEEK_SET) == -1){
                    perror("fseek error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if(fprintf(writeFp, "%c", car) != 1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "fprintf error. Terminating...\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }               

                if(kill(pid1, SIGCONT) == -1){
                    perror("F2 kill error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                printf("F2 : i've written '%c'\n", car); fflush(stdout);

                if(fscanf(rfpF2, "%c", &car) == EOF)
                    break;
                else{
                    if(fseek(rfpF2, -sizeOfChar, SEEK_CUR)){
                        perror("fseek error");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    raise(SIGSTOP);
                }
            }

            fclose(rfpF2);  
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:    
            /* P1 : Father */

            // Wait for the children to be interrupted by SIGSTOP (which changes their states)
            if(wait(NULL) == -1){
                perror("wait 1 error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if(wait(NULL) == -1){
                perror("wait 2 error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            // P1 is the first to be reading and writing...
            while(fscanf(rfpP1, "%c", &car) != EOF){

                if(fseek(writeFp, 0L, SEEK_SET) == -1){
                    perror("fseek error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                if(fprintf(writeFp, "%c", car) != 1){
                    fprintf(stderr, "fprintf error. Terminating...\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                if(kill(pid2, SIGCONT) == -1){
                    perror("P kill error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                printf("P1 : i've written '%c'\n", car); fflush(stdout);

                if(fscanf(rfpP1, "%c", &car) == EOF)
                    break;
                else{
                    if(fseek(rfpP1, -sizeOfChar, SEEK_CUR)){
                        perror("fseek error");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    raise(SIGSTOP);
                }

            }

            fclose(rfpP1);  
            break;
}

// Wait for the children...
if(wait(NULL) == -1){
    perror("wait 1 error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(wait(NULL) == -1){
    perror("wait 2 error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fclose(writeFp);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: If so, the instructor is incompetent, because the synchronization design in the assignment has inherent and unfixable race conditions (one process may not yet have finished raising the `SIGSTOP` for itself when another process tries to wake it up with `SIGCONT`, resulting in lost wakeups). Basically stop/cont signals should **never** be used for synchronization.

Comment: By the way, if the instructor isn't a complete asshole, you might get more credit for demonstrating why his/her design cannot work than you'd get for implementing it.. ;-)

Comment: Maybe the instructor was thinking about other signals like SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2?

Comment: The first time i wrote this code, i actually used SIGUSR1 (whose handler did nothing except freeing a process from a pause call) and pause() instead of SIGCONT and raise(SIGSTOP). I changed that, thinking that the father should have started with the readings and writings only after the two children entered the pause call. So, in the father, i wait for them before entering the while loop, knowing that stopping them, would cause a changing in their states (which permits the return from wait).

Comment: @R.. i agree with the fact that signals shouldn't be used to sychronize processes... however even in "Advanced Unix Programming in the Unix Environment" is showed how this can be done between a father and a child (though it's strongly discouraged).

Comment: @user996922: Any approach with `pause` has the exact same race condition. You have to use an approach like `sigwait` or `pselect` (or emulating `pselect` with a self-pipe and `select`) that atomically unmasks/masks the signal along with waiting for it to avoid the race condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to-do this would be to utilize the `sigwait()` function with a signal mask set to the signal you want to wait on.  First, before you can use `sigwait()`, you should make sure that the signal you are waiting on is first blocked in the signal mask of the process or thread.  Then, do the following:

1. In the parent, open all the appropriate file descriptors for the files you're going to be reading and writing from
2. Set the signal mask of the parent process so that you're blocking the signal you're going to be using for synchronization between the parent and child processes.
3. Fork the child processes.  After setting up the processing, in a while-loop, call `sigwait()` with a signal mask that only includes the synchronization signal.  When the synchronization signal is received by that child process, it will continue through the while-loop.  Before completing the loop and repeating the blocking call to `sigwait()`, send a signal to the next process.
4. In the parent process, using a while-loop do the first read/write sequence, and then send a signal to the next child process. Finally, call `sigwait()` at the end of the loop.

So in the end your child processes would look something like:

```
//child process

//...setup the child process

while (/* some condition for stopping */)
{
    int signal
    sigwait(&signal_mask, &signal)

    //check to make sure we're getting the right signal
    if (signal != synchronization_signal)
        continue;

    //...more code for reading/writing to files

    //send a signal to next process in-line
    //i.e., F1 will send a signal to F2, and F2 will signal P1    
}
```

and your parent process would look like:

```
//...block the synchronization signal and fork the children

while (/* some condition for stopping */)
{
    //...perform the reading and writing to the files

    //send signal to F1

    //block waiting for the signal to arrive from F2
    while (true)
    {
        int signal;
        sigwait(&signal_mask, &signal);

        //check to make sure we're getting the right signal
        if (signal == synchronization_signal)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `sigwait`, one of the only ways to make non-racy signal-based synchronization